# Issues plotting a histogram of a csv file on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to google colab and I am trying to plot a histogram of a csv file using matplotlib, but getting error.

This code is able to read and show my data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl

df = pd.read_csv('tree_result.csv')
df
```

but when I try to plot a histogram with two fields from the data, I get an error

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (50,10))
x = df['spc_common']
y = df['count']
plt.bar(x, height=y,align = 'center', width = 0.8)
plt.xlabel('Name of Trees (common name)', size = 10)
plt.ylabel('Number of Trees', size = 10)
pl.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

error message

```
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I changed the datatype to string. That fixed it issue

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (50,10))
x = df['spc_common'].astype(str)
y = df['count']
plt.bar(x, height=y,align = 'center', width = 0.8)
plt.xlabel('Name of Trees (common name)', size = 10)
plt.ylabel('Number of Trees', size = 10)
pl.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```